# How to convert a text with data in series having field name on left to a table in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, ms-office, ms-office-script

I need to convert a dataset in series to a table in Excel. The dataset has field names on the left side in order and each dataset is one after another vertically. I want to have a common primary row with field names on top and the fields data below it one after another. Please tell me how can I do this?

Example:

Dataset:

```
Name: Max
Age:23
Grade: A
Name: Paul
Age: 24
Grade: B
Name: John
Age:23
Grade:D
```

To table:

| Name | Age | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 23 | A |
| Paul | 24 | B |
| John | 23 | D |

I tried copying each field to the top row in workbook and copying each data one after another but it is taking long time and I want a quicker way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula: in cell E1

`=VSTACK(TRANSPOSE(A1:A3),WRAPROWS(B1:B9,3))`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(data,A1:A9,
cleanData,SUBSTITUTE(data,": ",":"),
tabData,WRAPROWS(TEXTAFTER(cleanData,":"),3),
header,TOROW(TEXTBEFORE(TAKE(cleanData,3),":")),
VSTACK(header,tabData))
```

It first removes obsolete blanks after the colon.

Then takes the part after the colon - and applies `WRAPROWS` after each 3rd row.

[image]